# getting difference for variable per year

Tags: r, dplyr, difference

I would like to get the difference for consecutive years in a data frame like this:

```
    group year value
    1     2017 10
    1     2018 20
    1     2019 25
    2     2017 5
    2     2018 10
    2     2019 15
```

If I use the following code I cannot get the right years to allign for the difference.

```
    df%>% 
      group_by(group) %>% 
      summarise(difference= abs(diff(value)))
```

How do I include the year so that I get the difference for the group per year?

Comment: If you change your `summarize(...)` statement to `mutate(difference = abs(value - lag(value)))` it will return the years difference (and `NA` for the first year in each group). Note this only works since there are no gaps in the years (as is the case in your sample data). Is this the outcome you want? If not, please edit your question to include the desired outcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

# Creating a data frame
df <- data.frame(
  group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  year = c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2017, 2018, 2019),
  value = c(10, 20, 25, 5, 10, 15)
)

# get nominal differences
diffs <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(difference = value - lag(value)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  arrange(group)

diffs
```